# Double authentication in GWT / EXT + Spring Security application

Tags: java, gwt, extjs, spring-security, interceptor

I have problems with double authentication. I have implemented the authentication form through pop-up window which is always on top. But I have problem probably with interceptors that cause the authentication request by Tomcat even before the start of application:

> A username and password are being requested by http://127.0.0.1:8888.
>   The site says: "Spring Security Application"

If I disable interceptors, I see in log that SecurityContextHolder treats user as Anonymous.

So my question is:
Can I somehow disable that first Tomcat login screen?

My Spring-security configuration XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">


<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="com.myCompany.model.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider" >
    <beans:property name="databaseId"    value="${configuration.databaseId}" />
    <beans:property name="applicationId" value="${configuration.applicationId}" />
</beans:bean>

<http auto-config="true" >
        <intercept-url pattern="/myApp/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/MyApp.html*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/gwt/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.html" access="ROLE_USER"/>

        <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" filters="none"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

        <http-basic />  
</http>

<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Your problem is, Spring Security is based on redirections. I once tried to fight with it, but it required to go too deep into SS internals, so I've resigned from this idea. Using SS to only filter channels is in my opinion too much overhead, simple HttpFilter is enough in that case.

Comment: @lechlukasz: I'm not really sure what you expect me to do. Can you write some detailed explanation?

I tried to remove all interceptors and leave only this one:

`<intercept-url pattern='/**' access='ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_CHANGE_PASS,ROLE_VIEWER,ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN'/>`

but SS treats user as anonymous even after the authentication.

Answer (score 1):

In case I understand your question in a correct way you have a problem with double authentication e.g. a *Tomcat* authentication or an *Apache Basic Auth* and the *Spring* authentication mechanism.

While the last project I had related problems with an *Apache Basic Auth* and the *Spring* security mechanism. Before launch I had the task to "protect" the access to the site by an simple *Apache Basic Auth*. By enabling this in the *Apache* configuration *Spring* started to do the same: **"Spring Security Application"** has been shown all the time

The solution for this behaviour was to **disable the auto-config**:

```xml
<security:http auto-config="false" ...>
    ...
</security:http>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not too clear. You mention a Tomcat login screen, which I assume is the first screen of your web application, to allow a user to sign in.

If this is correct, and your login page is named, say login.html, all you have to do is configure the interceptors to allow anonymous access to this page-

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**/login.*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/gwt/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/**/*.html" access="ROLE_USER"/>

<intercept-url pattern="/css/**" filters="none"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
```